# MSBuild backup files (with time stamp) before replacing

Tags: msbuild

I currently use a web deployment project to update an existing web site through various MSBuild tasks

Taking site offline:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <CreateItem Include="..\website\App_Code\override\App_Offline.htm">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="AppOffline" />
  </CreateItem>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(AppOffline)" DestinationFiles="@(AppOffline->'\\servername\f$\web\example.com\wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  <RemoveDir Directories="\\servername\f$\web\example.com\wwwroot\bin\" />
</Target>
```

Update files:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <CreateItem Include=".\Release\**\*">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="ReleaseFiles" />
  </CreateItem>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ReleaseFiles)" ContinueOnError="true" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" DestinationFiles="@(ReleaseFiles->'\\servername\f$\web\example.com\wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  <Delete Files="\\servername\f$\web\example.com\wwwroot\App_Offline.htm" />
</Target>
```

However, what I also want to do is backup the existing site before overwriting anything, into a timestamped zip (or 7zip) file, e.g. if done on 3rd October 2011 at 10:35 file would be named `\\servername\f$\web\example.com\backup201110031035.7z` containing the contents of the wwwroot folder (before taking the site offline and deleting the bin directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org) provide support for both, zipping and getting the (formatted) current time through the `Zip` and `Time` tasks respectively.

Once the MSBuild community tasks are installed and [imported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) to your project, you can create a backup zip file by adding the following to the beginning of your `BeforeBuild` target.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FilesToZip Include="\\servername\f$\web\example.com\wwwroot\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Time Format="yyyyMMddhhmm">
  <Output TaskParameter="FormattedTime" PropertyName="Timestamp" />
</Time>
<Zip
  Files="@(FilesToZip)"
  ZipFileName="\\servername\f$\web\example.com\backup$(Timestamp).zip"
  WorkingDirectory="\\servername\f$\web\example.com\wwwroot" />
```